# Retrieve ViewBag Values which Are Set Inside View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How is it possible to read e.g. ViewBag.Title in places like Base Controller, Action Filters, etc. **after it has been set by the View**?

Comment: You can't read `ViewBag` after redirection, In your scenario you have to use `Sessions`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you mean by redirection?

Comment: Means `Viewbag` can be used just to send data from controller to view it losts its value when you redirect to some other action or controller even you can't use it in action filters and basecontroller instead use sessions.

Comment: Got that! Thanks. My scenario is to log titles for all visited pages. Is there any good way for accomplishing this? Thanks again

Comment: `log titles for all visited pages` ... well in my opinion you can use some client side stuff instead using sessions..you can write these logs in a file and read from there or you can use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`  or cookies for this purpose.

Comment: @codeRecap : Why not use "google analytics" instead of rebuilding the wheel ?
Great tutorial for beginner: https://moz.com/blog/absolute-beginners-guide-to-google-analytics

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the purpose of Viewbag is to send data from controller to the view, you can't do anything else with this container.

See: http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-3-applications/

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of ViewBag is to send data from Controller to View not in reverse. Viewbag provides access to data as dynamic properties.

On the other side such as in Base controller & Action filters we can get data from ActionExecutingContext or ActionExecutedContext variables.

We can also set data in ActionFilters as below

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext != null)
        {
            //set vlaue in context
            filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Add("VariableName", "Value of variable");
            //Log information
            Log("OnActionExecuting", filterContext.RouteData);
        }
    }
```